# PYTHON - win32gui.DrawText rect even pattern

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32, win32gui

My applicaton is really simple. It just displays 12 (text) data in my Window using `win32gui.DrawText`.
However I am having trouble positioning the text or to be more precise the `rect`s.
My `rect`s always turn out uneven or they are shorter or longer than intended.
However I want all of them to be even, I want them to share the space the Window is providing.

What I am trying to archive is this Schema:

[image: WINDOW text app Schema]

Also note how in the first `rect` the text is aligned left and in the second its aligned right. Repeating this pattern.

I'm a newbie and Ive not been able to figure out how to get the rect tuple coordinates to behave this way.

**EDIT**: code (I removed unrelated code)

```
   thistuple2 = (145, 160, 0, 0)

   thistuple3 = (305, 60, 0, 0)
   thistuple4 = (305, 160, 20, 0)

   thistuple5 = (315, 60, 180, 0)
   thistuple6 = (315, 160, 180, 0)

   hDC, paintStruct = win32gui.BeginPaint(fenster)
   
   dpiScale = win32ui.GetDeviceCaps(hDC, win32con.LOGPIXELSX) / 60.0
   fontSize = 10
   lf = win32gui.LOGFONT()
   lf.lfFaceName = "Segoe UI"
   lf.lfHeight = int(round(dpiScale * fontSize))

   hf = win32gui.CreateFontIndirect(lf)
   win32gui.SelectObject(hDC, hf)
            
   win32gui.SetBkMode(hDC, win32con.TRANSPARENT)
   win32gui.SetTextColor(hDC,win32api.RGB(255,255,255))

   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "VLO ",
            -1,
            thistuple1,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER | win32con.DT_RIGHT)


   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "DFH ",
            -1,
            thistuple2,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "130242",
            -1,
            thistuple3,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER | win32con.DT_RIGHT)

   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "120",
            -1,
            thistuple4,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER | win32con.DT_RIGHT)


   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "VHN ",
            -1,
            thistuple5,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

   rect = win32gui.GetClientRect(fenster)
   win32gui.DrawText(
            hDC,
            "LOU ",
            -1,
            thistuple6,
            win32con.DT_SINGLELINE | win32con.DT_CENTER | win32con.DT_VCENTER)

   win32gui.EndPaint(fenster, paintStruct)
```

I know these are only 6 Items. I stopped drawing the remaining ones, because I was getting a headache with the rect coordinates.
Also in the final product the text is not static, just here for display purposes.

EDIT:
I managed to archive it myself yesterday by just giving all the rects flashy bg color and manually guessing the rect coordinates over and over again until I managed to place them where I wanted them and I fixed the alignment as well. Since I am new to py I didn't know there are things like Qt and their library, I'll redo the application with it since its easier to dynamically change a label instead of redrawing everytime with DrawText when the data changes.

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: @SuperUser Yes Sir, thank you for answering, I provided a code snippet. I am not competent enough to figure out the coordinates and the alignment settings to make this display pretty.

Comment: Please post **all** the code ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also what are the desired dimensions for the rectangles? What's the window dimension? What about the spaces in between, or the ones between 1st and last and the edges?  You'll have to provide some of that data.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be even, you need [Mapping Modes and Translations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/mapping-modes-and-translations).
Typically, The calling function sequence is like this [Drawing a Custom Window Background](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/drawing-a-custom-window-background):

```
    hdc = (HDC) wParam; 
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc); 
    SetMapMode(hdc, MM_ANISOTROPIC); 
    SetWindowExtEx(hdc, 100, 100, NULL); 
    SetViewportExtEx(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom, NULL);
    //possible SetWindowOrgEx and SetViewportOrgEx following
```

[image: Coordinate Spaces and Transformations]

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for answering. Thank you for your input, I like your approach.. I managed to archive it myself yesterday by just giving all the rects flashy bg color and manually guessing the rect coordinates over and over again until I managed to place them where I wanted them and I fixed the alignment as well. Since I am new to py I didn't know there are things like Qt and their library, I'll redo the application with it since its easier to change a label instead of redrawing everytime with DrawText.